# How to do static routing via next hop address?

Tags: cisco, ip-routing, static-routes

i know the command is `ip route [remote address] [next hop address]` but how do i implement it?
Currently these are the only ones that are connected:

```
CALOOCAN - MAKATI
MAKATI - NAVOTAS
SWITCH0-PC0-PC1
SWITCH1-PC2-PC3
SWITCH2-PC4-PC5
```

Here's the visualization:

[image: Here]

Comment: What do you want to route where?

Comment: @Marki from a router to know all of the networks so it can connect to all. For example i want my CALOOCAN router to know the network with 64 hosts. Is `ip route 172.16.6.0 255.255.255.128 172.16.6.129` correct? Because i tried that and i tried to ping it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Technically, CALOOCAN and NAVOTAS only need a default route pointing to MAKATI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create different routing tables on each router because you are always routing to the nearest transit network endpoint. The next router then takes it from there. So it should be something like this:

- NAVOTAS

  ```
  ip route 172.16.4.0 255.255.254.0 172.16.6.150
  ip route 172.16.6.0 255.255.255.128 172.16.6.150
  ```
- MAKATI

  ```
  ip route 172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.6.145
  ip route 172.16.4.0 255.255.254.0 172.16.6.142
  ```
- CALOOCAN

  ```
  ip route 172.16.6.0 255.255.255.128 172.16.6.129
  ip route 172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.6.129
  ```

Probably you should get some professional assistance.

Comment: The image is from Cisco Packet Tracer, so my guess is that this is homework and not a real network.

Comment: There goes the next generation level 1 support people ... ;-)